# Adding up rows in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

Oke so i have this thing. I want to know the amount of orders per week per entity.
I started with this query:

```
select 
DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate) AS 'Year',
DATEPART(WEEK, OrderDate) AS 'Week',
COUNT(*) as 'Amount of Orders',
EntityID
FROM tblOrder
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, tblOrder.OrderDate) = 2015
GROUP BY EntityID,OrderDate
ORDER BY Week asc
```

The result is good but i get double rows everywhere:

```
Year | Week | Amount of Orders | EntityID
2015 |  1   |        1         |     1
2015 |  1   |        1         |     1
2015 |  1   |        1         |     1
2015 |  1   |        1         |     1
2015 |  1   |        1         |     1
2015 |  1   |        1         |    15  
2015 |  1   |        1         |    15
```

What i want to achieve is:

```
Year | Week | Amount of Orders | EntityID
2015 |  1   |        5         |     1
2015 |  1   |        2         |     2
2015 |  1   |        4         |     3
2015 |  1   |        9         |     4
```

And so on. What is going wrong in my query?

Comment: i think that `GROUP BY EntityID,OrderDate` may be causing it. `OrderDate` is no doubt a totally unique entity, thus the seperate rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` year and week instead of orderdate:

```
select [Year], [week], EntityID, count(*)
from
(
select DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate) AS 'Year',
       DATEPART(WEEK, OrderDate) AS 'Week',
       EntityID
FROM tblOrder
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, tblOrder.OrderDate) = 2015
) dt
GROUP BY [Year], [Week], EntityID
ORDER BY Week asc
```

Because the same year/week can have orders from different dates. If you GROUP BY date, you'll get several rows for that year/week.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the same expression in your group by clause.

```
select DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate) AS 'Year',
       DATEPART(WEEK, OrderDate) AS 'Week',
       EntityID,
       COUNT(*) as 'Amount of Orders'
FROM tblOrder
WHERE DATEPART(YEAR, tblOrder.OrderDate) = 2015
GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, OrderDate), DATEPART(WEEK, OrderDate), EntityID
```